# C# - make an Ascending secondary Array

Tags: c#, arrays

i want to make a secondary array input from user and make those number Ascending from lower to high, i can't find the wrong
i can do this code in array with one element that can be easy, but i want to this Ascending with two element.

that is my code

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] Matrice = new int[2, 3];
            int i, j, m, n, temp;

            for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter The Number :(" + i + "," + j + ")");
                    Matrice[i, j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            }

            for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)

            for (m = i + 1; m < 2; m++)
               for (n = j + 1; n < 3; n++)

            if (Matrice[i, j] > Matrice[m,n])
            {
                temp = Matrice[i,j];
                Matrice[i, j] = Matrice[m, n];
                Matrice[m, n] = temp;
            }

            for (i = 0; i <2; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j <3; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Ascending from low to high :(" + i + "," + j + ") est " + Matrice[i, j]);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

my output is Wrong like that:

```
Enter The Number :(0,0)
5
Enter The Number :(0,1)
3
Enter The Number :(0,2)
8
Enter The Number :(1,0)
15
Enter The Number :(1,1)
3
Enter The Number :(1,2)
9
Ascending from low to high :(0,0) est 3
Ascending from low to high :(0,1) est 3
Ascending from low to high :(0,2) est 8
Ascending from low to high :(1,0) est 15
Ascending from low to high :(1,1) est 5
Ascending from low to high :(1,2) est 9
```

i need help :)

Comment: This isn't a very good question at the moment, as you are dumping your code and saying "It doesn't work!". You need to narrow down the source of your problem with a debugger and ask about that. Also, consider just using `OrderBy`

Comment: i am not good in english sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you skip the first item of the second part of the array since you start at i+1. You want to walk through each element and compare it, so just use:

```
for (m = 0; m < 2; m++)
    for (n = 0; n < 3; n++)
```

Second, you want the values to be ascending, your current code is sorting descending. To fix this, just change the '>' to '<'

```
if (Matrice[i, j] < Matrice[m, n])
```

The stacked for-loops will now look like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                for (m = 0; m < 2; m++)
                    for (n = 0; n < 3; n++)
                        if (Matrice[i, j] < Matrice[m, n])
                        {
                            temp = Matrice[i, j];
                            Matrice[i, j] = Matrice[m, n];
                            Matrice[m, n] = temp;
                        }
```

Which should do what you want if I understand your question correctly.

PS: As BradleyDotNET said, you might want to take a look at OrderBy to make this easier/more efficient.